# On a constant defined by Ramanujan.

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, constants

In the second letter to Hardy Ramanujan writes about the number of prime numbers less than $n$ there he writes.[image]

Here this constant $\mu$ facinated me . What is its closed form? and  How to compute more digits of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Ramanujan-Soldner constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Soldner_constant).